# "Smash down on" when the meaning is not about a thing that breaks

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrasal-verbs, dictionaries

I have some troubles with figuring out whether "smash down on" in the following sentences is the phrasal verb (smash down) or the regular verb "smash" + down on sth.

> A two-year-old toddler tragically died after a six-foot tall mirror
> **smashed down on** her head while she was trying on a pair of shoes
> inside..
>
> A bridge collapsed in northeastern Taiwan on Tuesday injuring at least
> 14 people as it **smashed down on** to fishing vessels ...

Looking in several dictionaries, "smash down" does not have a meaning that would fit in here, esp. with the "on" preposition. The usual example sentences are "The police smashed down the door."

- Webster: to hit (something) hard so that it breaks and falls down
- Macmillan: to make something fall down and break into pieces by hitting it very hard

This would imply that the thing must broke as a result but that does not fit into other sentences, such as:

> ...South African coast after a 40-ton whale jumped from the waters and
> smashed down on top of a sailing instructor's boat.

In this sentence, what dictionary entry would be the right one to describe the meaning of "smash down" + on?

Comment: In [this Lexico result](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/smash) see definitions 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, and especially 2. Although it is often true, you can use "smash" without the object being broken or destroyed; it can simply be a more colorful and intense replacement for "hit" or "impact."

Comment: The dictionary examples are a transitive usage - 'smash [something] down'. In your two examples it is intransitive and means 'fall with a smash' (a violent impact).

Comment: (Also, it's irrelevant to your question—but it certainly sounds like the objects of "smash" in these examples *did* break.)

Comment: In my haste, I overlooked the main point, as @KateBunting points out: Yes, although there are obviously *things that got smashed* in these examples, the verb is being used without a direct object. The bridge *smashed* (an action that it does), and then "down onto ___" just explains more about that action. "I smashed the vase" makes "the vase" an actual grammatical object.

Comment: I don't think "smash down" is really ever a phrasal verb.  Something is smashed, and the way in which it is smashed is down.  Compare to "look up a reference", which cannot be separated into its literal parts - you are not "looking a reference" and the way in which you look it is "up".

Comment: Transitive to ***smash down** [on something]* is just a [relatively uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+fell+down+on%2Cit+smashed+down+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20fell%20down%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20smashed%20down%20on%3B%2Cc0) emphatic / colloquial alternative to ***fall down** [on it]*.  Intransitive *Jack **fell down** [and broke his crown]* wouldn't normally be expressed emphatically using ***smash***, and it won't always sound idiomatic anyway, so it's probably best avoided.